# Event with the same timing as BufEnter but triggers on vsplit?

Tags: buffers, vim-windows

As title. I have a pair of autocmds which needs each other:

1. One on `WinLeave`, this one is fine since it will be triggered when I call `:vsplit`.
2. One on `BufEnter`, this one is NOT fine for the edge case, i.e. `:vsplit`.

Every time `WinLeave` happens, it will call a function, which expects a pairing-function to be called on `BufEnter`. If I have no buffer opened in many windows, then no problem. But I just realized that calling `:vsplit` create the only edge case: `BufEnter` will not be triggered, thus the function from `WinLeave` will not be paired with the pairing-function from `BufEnter`.

I did try `WinEnter` but it doesn't satisfy my requirement. That is: the timing is different. `BufEnter` is called later than `WinEnter`. If I use `WinEnter` then the pairing-function will be called too early. So is there any way so that `BufEnter` can also be triggered on the same buffer in different window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misuse autocmds. There's no "timing" here. Bufleave/bufenter are triggered if and only if active buffer changes. But when the same buffer is opened in both windows it doesn't change, obviously. And so there is no (and must be no) events other than winnew/winleave/winenter. This is not a sort of corner case. This is how Vim interface works precisely: splitting changes windows but not buffers, editing changes buffers but not windows etc.etc.

This is a user who decides what to do. And events are simply results of decisions he made. You (programmer) must not dictate but comply.

So what you need is to rethink the way events work in Vim and to revise your program logic.

Comment: But with `:h WinEnter` I see `If the window is for another buffer, Vim executes the BufEnter autocommands after the WinEnter autocommands.` I'm using neovim though.

Comment: And I said this in my OP because I already did some testing: if I instead use `WinEnter` for my point 2., then the animation(created by plugin) did not get played at the right timing as `BufEnter`. While I haven't read the source, but it seems that `BufEnter` does get called later than `WinEnter`.

Comment: Even without testing: The author(s) of docs did use words like `After BufAdd`, `After BufReadPost`(`:h BufEnter`). Or maybe we have different interpretations regarding the word "timing".

Comment: @job_start This should be understood as follows: if some action causes both events at once (e.g. both winleave and bufleave, or both bufread and bufenter) then the events will be triggered in this order... It doesn't mean it is always like that. Sometimes, only a single event will be fired.

Comment: OK, while I still don't understand it fully, I agree with your last point that I probably should not rely on these events to implement the function I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need points but I here to prove that there is indeed timing regarding events:

### Logs

Based on the logs, The timing of `BufEnter` getting called is always **after** `WinEnter`.

```
06:24:00 msg_show WinEnter is called
06:24:00 msg_show BufEnter is called
06:24:01 msg_show WinEnter is called
06:24:01 msg_show BufEnter is called
   Error  06:24:06 msg_show.lua_error WinEnter is called
06:24:06 msg_show BufEnter is called
06:24:08 msg_show WinEnter is called
06:24:08 msg_show BufEnter is called
06:24:11 msg_show WinEnter is called
06:24:11 msg_show BufEnter is called
06:24:12 msg_show WinEnter is called
06:24:12 msg_show BufEnter is called
```

### To reproduce in NeoVim:

1. Add this to your neovim config:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'BufEnter' }, {
  pattern = '*',
  callback = function ()
    print('BufEnter is called')
  end
})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'WinEnter' }, {
  pattern = '*',
  callback = function ()
    print('WinEnter is called')
  end
})
```

2. Create many splits and jump among them.

Comment: And now try to trace edit or buffer commands...

Comment: OK, I assume you're right. But isn't that out of my concern, since in this post I only care about the ordering of `BufEtner` and `WinEnter`? I will schedule a time to try it after I finish my plugin.